# SQL or MSEXCEL transpose data from rows to columns NOT PIVOT nor TRANSFORM

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, pivot, transform

I am trying to use transpose/pivot (SQL Server 2008), however neither MAX function, nor TRANSFORM works for me. Is there a way to achieve this differently, or by using MSEXCEL?

This is what I have

`

```
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Question</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 1</td><td>Question 1</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 1</td><td>Question 2</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 1</td><td>Question 3</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 1</td><td>Question 4</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 1</td><td>Question 5</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 2</td><td>Question 1</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 2</td><td>Question 2</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 2</td><td>Question 3</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 2</td><td>Question 4</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 2</td><td>Question 5</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 3</td><td>Question 1</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 3</td><td>Question 2</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 3</td><td>Question 3</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 3</td><td>Question 4</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 3</td><td>Question 5</td><td>Answer</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

`

And I would like to end up with the follwoing:

`

```
<table>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>Question 1</td><td>Question 2</td><td>Question 3</td><td>Question 4</td><td>Question 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 1</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 2</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td></tr>
<tr><td>Respondent 3</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td></tr>
</table>
```

`

This is the query I tried and failed with:
SELECT
Respondent,
MAX(CASE WHEN Question='Question 1' THEN Answer ELSE NULL END) AS ‘Question 1’,
MAX(CASE WHEN Question='Question 2' THEN Answer ELSE NULL END) AS ‘Question 2’
FROM Table 
GROUP BY  Respondent

I think Excel would probably be the best solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pivot table in sql:

```
Select * from tablename
Pivot( max(Answer) for Question in ([Question1], [Question2],[Question3],[Question4],[Question5])) as pivotTable
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, I get: Operand data type ntext is invalid for max operator. Cannot use MAX function

Comment: Yea, MAX works on varchar or nvarchar, see if you can change it from ntext to varchar and it should work.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to show me how to incorporate the varchar in the query you provided above?

Comment: You can alter the column datatype:

ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN Answer VARCHAR(MAX)